# 404 Partitioned topic does not exist

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am trying to delete a Namespace in Apache Pulsar but I am getting the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Partitioned topic does not exist
```

The command I am running is:

```
pulsar-admin namespaces delete -f tenant/namespace
```

If I now list my namespaces I can still see my namespace, but if I try and list the topics I see the following:

```
pulsar-admin topics list tenant/namespace
Namespace is deleted

Reason: Namespace is deleted
```

This is stopping me from deleting my tenant as it still thinks the namespace exists.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to log into ZooKeeper and delete the following:

```
deleteall /managed-ledgers/{tenant}/{namespace}
deleteall /admin/partitioned-topics/{tenant}/{namespace}
```